# Not able to install pyaudio or portaudio packages. It is showing error

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, portaudio

I am using google colab. But for some reason I am having problems with vscode.
It is showing this error msg for

`pip install portaudio`:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement portaudio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for portaudio
```

`pip install pyaudio`:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have installed wheels already and also tried using pipwin

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pyaudio is not available as a pre-built package for Colab, which is why you are seeing the "No matching distribution found" error. Similarly, the error with pyaudio could be due to various missing dependencies or configuration issue in the Colab environment. To install the missing dependencies, you could run this command.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu:

```bash
!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg
```

And then trying to install pyaudio again.

```bash
!pip install pyaudio --upgrade
```